# Retorno em um DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, if, data.frame, pandas

Boa tarde.
Eu tenho uma dúvida em relação ao Python.
Tenho um if onde tem a condicional e else, o else ele processa mais de uma arquivo e eu preciso salvar toda informação que ele ler dentro de um DataFrame, existe uma forma de fazer isso?

O code que estou utilizando:

```
for idx, arquivo in enumerate(fileLista):
    if arquivo == 'nome_do_arquivo_para_tratamento':
        df1 = pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
        df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
        tratativaUm = df1[[informacoes das colunas que vão ser utilizadas]]

     else:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
        df2.columns  = df2.columns.str.strip()
        TratativaDois = df2[[informacoes das colunas que vão ser utilizadas]]

####atribuir resultado de cada arquivo recebido no else

frames = [tratativaUm, tratativaDois] 
titEmpresa = pd.concat(frames)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ? 
Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

Pressupondo que todos os arquivos lidos tenho a mesma estrutura, cada DataFrame criado no `else` terá as mesmas colunas. Logo, basta acrescentar os DataFrames lidos no DataFrame resultado em cada iteração.

```py
# Inicializar DataFrame resultado
tratativaDois = pd.DataFrame()    

for idx, arquivo in enumerate(fileLista):
    if arquivo == 'nome_do_arquivo_para_tratamento':
        df1 = pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
        df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
        tratativaUm = df1[[informacoes das colunas que vão ser utilizadas]]

    else:
       df2 = pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
       df2.columns  = df2.columns.str.strip()

       # Acrescentar novo DataFrame lido
       tratativaDois = tratativaDois.append(df2[[informacoes das colunas que vão ser utilizadas]])
```